# Show that $f(a)=\frac{ ((a+1)^k+a^k+1 )^2}{2} -a^{2k}- (a+1)^{2k}-1$ is negative for $k>2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I would like to show the for
\begin{align}
f(a)=\frac{ ((a+1)^k+a^k+1 )^2}{2} -a^{2k}- (a+1)^{2k}-1
\end{align}

for $a\ge 0$ we have that
\begin{align}
f(a) \ge 0, \text{ for } k< 2\\
f(a) =0, \text{ for } k=2\\
f(a) \le 0 , \text{ for } k> 2
\end{align}
I am not quite sure fot inequality to use?

For example using $(c+d)^k \le 2^k(c+d)$ is not enough.

Comment: Fix your title - it references $p$, not $k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my computations are correct you have
$$-2f(a)=((a+1)^k-(a^{k/2}+1)^2)((a+1)^k-(a^{k/2}-1)^2) $$
hence this is
$$((a+1)^{k/2}-a^{k/2}-1)((a+1)^{k/2}+a^{k/2}+1)((a+1)^{k/2}-a^{k/2}+1)((a+1)^{k/2}+a^{k/2}-1)$$
Hence you have only to look at the sign of these $4$ expressions, and this seems not difficult (I have not done these last computations)

Added:

Note that $a^{2k}f(1/a)=f(a)$, so wlog we may suppose (if needed) that $a\geq 1$. Put $G(x)=(a+1)^x -a^x-1$. The derivative of $G$ is $G^{\prime}(x)=\log(a+1)(a+1)^x-(\log a) a^x=a^{x}(\log(a+1)(1+1/a)^x-(\log a))$, this is $\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$. As $G(1)=0$, this prove the inequality for $0\leq x\leq 1$. For $x<0$, we have $(a+1)^x<1$, hence the inequality.

Comment: So, it seems that the key is to show that  $(a+1)^{k/2} - (a^{k/2}+1)$ is negative if $k<2$ and positive for $k>2$. It is certanly true that $(a+1)^{k/2} \ge (a^{k/2}+1)$ for $k\ge 2$.  Is it true that   $(a+1)^{k/2}  \le  (a^{k/2}+1)$ for $k<2$ ???

Comment: @Boby I have added some explanations.